# Python: Issue with Import MySQLdb statement

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-workbench

When I use include mysqldb statement I get an error that the module cannot be found. How do I install the module in MySQL workbench 6.3?

Comment: Need more information. What statement and where do you execute it? And what operating system?

Comment: Windows 7. I'm running the scripting in mysql workbench 6.3. When I get to the import mysqldb statement it indicates module could not be found.